# Backtransforming a PyTorch Tensor

Tags: pytorch, transformation, generative-adversarial-network

I have trained a WGAN on the [CelebA dataset](http://mmlab.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/projects/CelebA.html) in PyTorch following this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pG0QZ7OddX4). Since I do this on Google Cloud Platform where TensorBoard is not availabe, I save one figure of generated images by the GAN every epoch to see how the GAN is actually doing.

Now, the saved pdf files look sth like this: [generated images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWJu1.png). Unfortunately, this is not really readable, and I suspect this has to do with the preprocessing I do:

```
trafo = transforms.Compose(
                    [transforms.Resize(size = (64, 64)),
                    transforms.ToTensor(), 
                    transforms.Normalize( mean = (0.5,), std = (0.5,))])
```

Is there any way to kind of undo this transformation when I save the image?

Currently, I save the image every epoch as follows:

```
visualization = torchvision.utils.make_grid(
                           tensor = gen(fixed_noise), 
                           nrow = 8, 
                           normalize = False)
plt.savefig("generated_WGAN_" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + ".pdf")
```

Also, I should probably mention that in the Jupyter notebook, I get the following warning:

"Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1]) for floats or [0..255] for integers)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your output pixel values are in range `[-1, 1]` (please verify this).
Therefore, when you save the images, the negative part is being clipped (as the error message you got suggests).

Try:

```py
visualization = torchvision.utils.make_grid(
                           tensor = torch.clamp(gen(fixed_noise), -1, 1) * 0.5 + 0.5,  # from [-1, 1] -> [0, 1]
                           nrow = 8, 
                           normalize = False)
plt.savefig("generated_WGAN_" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + ".pdf")
```

Comment: Hey Shai, I think there is a little mistake in your code, as you write in a comment in your code that you want go go from [-1, 1] to [0, 1] (yes, this is indeed the range of my images at the end), but you write -0.5 instead of + 0.5 at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The [`torchvision.transform.Normalize`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Normalize) function is usually used to standardize data (make `mean(data)=0` and `std(x)=1`) while the `normalize` option on [`torchvision.utils.make_grid`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/utils.html#torchvision.utils.make_grid) is used to normalize the data between `[0,1]` given a range. So no need to implement a function to fix this.

> If `True`, shift the image to the range `(0, 1)`, by the min and max values specified by range. Default: `False`.

Here you are looking to normalize between `0` and `1`. Given a tensor `x`:

```
torchvision.utils.make_grid(x, nrow=8, normalize=True, range=(x.min(), x.max()))
```

Here are [some examples of use](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bf16430f7750c023141c562f3e9f2a91) provided by the PyTorch's documentation.

---

Back to your original question, I should mention that `torchvision.transform.Normalize(mean=0.5, std=0.5)` **doesn't** transform your data such that it has `mean=0.5` and `std=0.5`... Neither will it standardize it to `mean=0`, `std=1`. You have to measure the mean and std from your dataset.

`torchvision.transform.Normalize` simply performs a shift-scale operation. To undo that just unscale-unshift with the same values:

```
>>> x = torch.rand(64, 3, 100, 100)*torch.rand(64, 1, 1, 1)
>>> x.mean(), x.std()
(tensor(0.2536), tensor(0.2175))

>>> t = T.Normalize(mean, std)
>>> t_inv = lambda x: x*std + mean

>>> x_after = t(x)
>>> x_after.mean(), x_after.std()
(tensor(-0.4928), tensor(0.4350))

>>> x_before = t_inv(x_after)
>>> x_before.mean(), x_before.std()
(tensor(0.2536), tensor(0.2175))
```